# Is it possibile to create aliases for postgresql queries?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create something like a query that gets called everytime I write an alias. So something like :

myalias = select codes from codetables where validity=current_date ;

then use it like :

select * from mainregistry where code in (myalias) ;

the "myalias" should be available everywhere everytime, so there should be a way of having it "default" in all my dbs.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a view:

```
CREATE VIEW myalias AS
SELECT codes
FROM codetables
WHERE validity=current_date;
```

and then:

```
SELECT * FROM mainregistry
WHERE code IN (SELECT codes FROM myalias);
```